# Relation Question on Partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let S be a set of positive integers and define a relation ρ on S as follows: ∀a, b ∈ S, aρb if and only if a ≤ b and a and b have the same number of positive divisors.

(a) Let S = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}. Draw an arrow diagram of ρ on the set S.

(b) Let S = Z+. Prove that (S, ρ) is a partial order.

I am stuck on part a) i am not to sure on how to draw an arrow diagram of ρ
while for part b), May i know how do i prove a statement to be a partial order.

Comment: For (a) write the numbers down. The numbers $1,2,3,5,7$ are have the same number of divisors and are linearly ordered in the usual order. Therefore $\rho$ orders them in that same order. Draw arrows from smaller to larger with respect to $\rho$. The numbers $6\leq8$ have the same number of divisors. Therefore $6\rho8$. Finally $4$ is lonely.

Comment: $1\to2\to3\to5\to7$, $6\to8$ and $4$. That would be the diagram. (b) follows from this, since $\rho$ is the disjoint union of those three linearly ordered sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) For this part you should draw an arrow from $i$ to $j$ if and only if $a \rho b$. As an example, you draw an arrow from $3$ to $5$ as $3 \leq 5$ and they have the same number of positive divisors.

b) You need to prove the axioms of partial order:
   i) reflexivity $a \rho a$. This is clear as $a \leq a$ and they have the same number of positive divisors.

ii) antisymmetry If $a \rho b$ and $ b \rho a$, then $a=b$. This follows easy $ a \rho b$ and $b \rho a$ implies $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a$ respectively, so $a=b$.

iii) transitivity If $a \rho b$ and $ b \rho c$, then $a \rho c$. I will this as an exercise.

Comment: does that mean to prove a statement is partial order i have to prove that its is AntiSymmetric and also the relations is Transitivity? Thank You!

Comment: The axioms of partial order are i) reflexivity, ii) antisymmetry and iii) transitivity as described in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set